# Git - Where can I find the source code that implements .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm interested in studying how Git implements .gitignore. Can some one point me at the specific source code file(s) in the git repo?  I'm looking for a 'toe-hold'.

Comment: `git grep gitignore -- *.c`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem useful to anyone but the author

Answer (score 4):

The file, `dir.c` in the top level of the `git/git.git` repository on github seems to contain the source code that handles the .gitignore file.

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/dir.c